# Codefirst Initializer Seed from data source

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

While the [Code First Database Evolution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx) is not yet available, I'd still like to keep some basic data in my database even during the development. My idea is to keep the data in a backup db, and automatically read it to the database on initialization.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDatabase>
{

    protected override void Seed(MyDatabase context)
    {
        var questions = new List<Question>
        {

            foreach(var row in MySecondDataSource)
            {
              new Question 
              {
                QuestionID = row.Column["a"]
                QuestionText = row.Column["b"],
                SortOrder = row.Column["c"],
                QuestionType = questionTypes.Find(q => q.QuestionTypeID == row.Column["d"]),
                Category = categories.Find(c => c.CategoryID == row.Column["e"]),
                Target = targets.Find(t => t.TargetID == row.Column["f"]),
                Unit = units.Find(u => u.UnitID == row.Column["g"])
              };
            }
        };

        questions.ForEach(q => context.Questions.Add(q));
```

Or any other ideas on how to go about keeping or reputting data to the database after dropping it?

Comment: I guess it's the best way, because wou'll get compile time error if your model change (a manual sql query to copy would be faster but you'll not get compile error if your model change)

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm really manually copying from a table in a backup to the new db, but that's really tedious and as the application is expanding I need more data, which means more work. I suppose a saved sql insert query containing all data would be all right too, but it's a days labour to write it!

Comment: At a point, you should try to manually apply model changes to the database to avoid the data drop. (my personnal though: Migrations is a very important feature for any ORM, I will not use Code First on a production project until it's available)

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about that, hopefully I've got most of my relations set up now, so it might be something like adding a column to a table somewhere. Should I be able to just update the DB and the model the same way and everything should be ok?

Comment: Yep take a look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the post but still didn't know it was that easy. I'll give it a shot. Much appreciated!